# Android set spinner's Dialog style \ theme

Tags: android, dialog, styles, themes, spinner

I successfully styling my spinner as I wished.
My spinner is in spinnerMode="Dialog" and I want to keep this.

The only problem I observe is a Top and Bottom Margin on the Dialog with the values.
I suppose this is due to the default Android Dialog Theme.

[image]

Can I edit\change\set\styling this?